# Geodesic distance and mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-mining, modeling

My data-set consists of points in globe. Suppose a User visits locations $l_1,l_2,\dots l_n$ (each location in $(lat, long)$ in the city with probability $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$ and I want to calculate the expected location visited by the user. How should I go about calculating that? If I use geodesic distance between points then do we have a formula or recipe to calculate geodesic expectation? What possibly can go wrong if I convert the individual $(lat,long)$ values to cartesian co-ordinates and calculate their expectation?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "expected location."  As to what can possibly go wrong when using Cartesian coordinates for global distance calculations, please visit the [GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=projection%20distance%20longitude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latitude and Longitude are tricky to handle directly.

You can however transform the data to **3D** space, then take the mean, and then scale that vector to the earth surface again. If the mean is absolute 0, then your data is rather evenly/symmetric distributed around the globe, and you are probably asking the wrong question; there is no "central" point. But when your data clusters somewhere, you should be fine.

Compute the *weighted* average in 3D coordinates
and project back to the spherical coordinates:

\begin{align}
P =& \sum_i p_i\\
\mu_x =& \frac{1}{P}\sum_i p_i\sin\phi_i \cos\psi_i\\
\mu_y =& \frac{1}{P}\sum_i p_i\sin\phi_i \sin\psi_i \\
\mu_z =& \frac{1}{P}\sum_i p_i\cos\phi_i\\
\phi_\mu =& \arccos \frac{\mu_z'}{\sqrt{\mu_x^2+\mu_y^2+\mu_z^2}}\\
\psi_\mu =& \arctan_2(\mu_y', \mu_x')
\end{align}

If you get a division by zero, then your points are distributed all around the globe, and there is no well-defined "mean" anymore. Just choose any of the input points: $\phi_\mu=\phi_1,\quad \psi_\mu=\psi_1$, or the one which has the smallest average (squared) distance to all others.

Comment: This approach works but its interpretation may be a challenge.  For instance, any two diametrically opposite points with equal weights will have a mean at zero. Now pick any subset of the globe--a particular path, say, such as the Equator--and select a finite set of points on it along with their diametric opposites. Give all these points equal weights, thereby placing their centroid at the origin.  In what sense would any such point distribution be adequately characterized as "equally distributed around the globe" and what value would such a description add to the understanding of the data?

Comment: For none of these examples, one can define a sensible "expected location" of the user. None is the most central point... it pretty much does not matter how you break these ties; for example by choosing any of the input points at random; or one that minimizes the smallest average distance to all others.
In either case, the input data is so broken, that the *intended* analysis has already failed before the math failed.

Comment: Implementation is just a few sin/cos operations, I don't see the challenge there. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: It might be going too far to claim the "input data is ... broken." Don't blame the data: look instead to the analysis. For instance, if the purpose is to minimize distances among the points, the problem becomes a traveling salesman problem on the globe. If it is to find a central point that minimizes distances, then in the case of the equatorial points the solutions will lie near either pole--but at least there are a finite number of definite solutions. This is why I believe more information is needed from the OP before we can hope to fashion--or evaluate--any defensible solution.

Comment: I was as much saying **the question is broken** if this happens, as I was saying the data is broken. Two sides of the same medal, your hypothesis ("clustered somewhere") not fitting the data, or your data not fitting the hypothesis ("clustered somewhere")

Comment: As far as "no challenge" in your proposed calculation goes, there are subtleties. It is essential to use an `atan2` function to compute $\psi_\mu$ rather than using the inverse tangent of the ratio--which would incorrectly limit the longitude to a 180 degree span. Note, too, that your formulas assume equal probabilities are associated with the points, whereas the question suggests those probabilities may vary from point to point (although it is unclear whether those probabilities are associated with points or with "visits," which might be paths on the Earth's surface).

Comment: Obviously `atan2` is the way to implement these equations in a computer, yes. You can easily add weights into these equations, no challenge from that (I've updated them for viewing pleasure). If your data is any real sensor measurements, the chance of having an exact zero mean and meanigful data for this task is effectively zero...